# How to apply hibernate filter for map datatype?

Tags: hibernate, filter, annotations

Is there a way to apply filter on map type attribute in a class using annotations? I have done something like below but the filter is not getting applied

```
public class EntityA
{
@id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name="id")
private Long id;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="EntityA")
@MapKeyColumn(name = "entityB_id")
@Filter(name = "percentFilter", condition="MODEL_PERCENT> :percent")
private Map<Long, EntityB> entityBMap;
} 

public class EntityB
{
@Column(name = "MODEL_PERCENT")
private BigDecimal modelPercent;

@ManyToOne
@joincolumn(name="entityA_id") 
private EntityA entityA; 
}
```

But if i change the **map** attribute to **list** as below, the filter works

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="EntityA")
@MapKeyColumn(name = "entityB_id")
@Filter(name = "percentFilter", condition="MODEL_PERCENT> :percent")
private Map<Long, EntityB> entityBMap;
```

to

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="EntityA")
@JoinColumn(name = "entityA_id")
@Filter(name = "percentFilter", condition="MODEL_PERCENT> :percent")
private List<EntityB> entityBList;
```

So i guess i need some help on annotating the map attribute such that the filter works. Any suggestion or sample code would be of great help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to apply the filter condition to the association table, so, use `@FilterJoinTable` and use property name, not database column name:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="EntityA")
@MapKeyColumn(name = "entityB_id")
@FilterJoinTable(name = "percentFilter", condition="modelPercent > :percent")
private Map<Long, EntityB> entityBMap;
```

Check [Filters](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#entity-hibspec-filters) of Hibernate Annotations documentation, you can find there an example.

Hope it helps.

**EDIT:**


Don't forget to enable filtering in your Hibernate Session:

```
session.enableFilter("percentFilter").setParameter("percent", "some-value");
```

Comment: Have you checked the link? are you enabling your filter in your session? `session.enableFilter("percentFilter").setParameter("percent", "some-value");`

Comment: Thanks jelies, it actually worked. i had commented the enable filter while i was trying out another approach. Thanks a million